# Can one viewflow task have multiple next state transitions?

Tags: django-viewflow

A finite state machine can transition into multiple next states. So e.g. from State1, the machine will transition into State2 given input A, or transition into State2 given input B, and so on. Is this possible with django-viewflow?

NB1 I'm aware that it is possible to 'split' workflows. This is an excellent feature but it isn't what I'm looking for. Split workflows provide multiple *concurrent* workflows, all proceeding individually. I'm looking for a way to choose between different *individual* workflows, where only one workflow will be chosen and executed, depending on input received.

NB2 It may be possible to achieve what I want using If gateways. Presumably one can store a flag *somewhere* depending on user input, which the If node then checks and uses to determine which branch to activate. Is this the recommended way of proceeding? If so, are there any specific code examples demonstrating how to do this? Ideally, I don't want to store this sort of workflow information as a flag in my main models - indeed, I don't want to store this ephemeral choice long term at all. So are there other ways of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of BPMN that it forces to program flow in such a way, that every process decisions are stored permanently and available for further process performance analysis. Skipping a decision store is the antipattern. In the cases where there are a lot of such decisions, In django, it's pretty easy to implement by adding a JSON field to a process model.

But viewflow customize everything. A transition selection could be implemented by overriding activation class done/activate_next methods.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.